# FIrebase push data into array. what is the proper syntax?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4, angular8

[image]

How can I push 7 entries into a messages array. I use the following syntax, but it's not working, it overrides an array 0 index.

```
this.signleChat.doc(id).set({messages:{}},{merge:true});
```

Please help to solve updated firebase query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add another entry in the messages array, do the following:

```
this.signleChat.doc(id).update({messages:{}});
```

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data):

> To update some fields of a document without overwriting the entire document, use the `update()` method.